# SSRS Report: Combine and pass multiple 'text' parameter in SQL IN clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

[image: Multiple text inputs]

I am new to SSRS and I am in process of writing a simple tabular `SSRS` report. As mentioned in the screenshot attached, I need to provide in total 12 parameters. Two dates (start and end) and 10 free form text values. My issue is around 10 free form input parameters.

Below is my SQL query representation.

**SQL Query**

```
select 
vsd.createdon 'DateEntered'
, act.mot_code 'ActCode', act.mot_description 'ActDescription'
from mot_violationsourcedocument vsd
left join mot_violation vio on vsd.mot_violationsourcedocumentid = vio.mot_documenttype
left join mot_actviolationtype act on vio.mot_actsection = act.mot_actviolationtypeid
where vsd.createdon between @StartDate and @EndDate
and act.mot_code in (@ActCode1,@ActCode2,@ActCode3,@ActCode4,@ActCode5,@ActCode6,@ActCode7,@ActCode8,@ActCode9,@ActCode10)
```

**NOTE**

It is not mandatory that user must pass all 10 parameters all the time. Sometime users may pass just 1 Act code or sometime they may pass 5 act codes or sometimes all 10 act code. Or sometimes they may not want to pass at all. Although they will have to select and provide desired date.

**ISSUE**

As mentioned above in SQL query, these free form text parameters points to 1 field in SQL table. That means I need to pass this 10 parameters in SQL IN clause. Now my complexity here is when I only pass one parameter the report displays data fine pertaining to that act code. The issue arises when I need to pass more than one act code value. Unfortunately I could not have access to SQL Query Profiler to trace the query runtime or don't know any other way to check what kind of query is being formed runtime or how the `SQL IN` clause looks like.
On each parameter, I have defined an expression as below.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ActCode1.Value="",Nothing,Parameters!ActCode1.Value)
```

But it is not much of any help.

Also note that, here the multi value parameter is not an option as there is numerous act codes and users would not like to stretch and scroll the drop down to find the desired code and generate report.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-Value parameters **are** an option. You do not have to use a list with them although they are not very intuitive.

I've created a simple example with a list of country names and codes (e.g. [Country Code] = "IT" and [Country] = "Italy")

A created a multi-value parameter called `CountryCode` but I did **not** set the available values.

I added a datset that looked like this

```
SELECT 
*
FROM myCountryTable
WHERE [Country Code] in (@CountryCode)
```

When I run the report, I get a blank multi-value parameter field. When you click this field you see an empty list but you can simply type values hitting `Enter` between each to start a new line.

Once all the values had been entered, I just hit "View Report" and got the following (I've included the parameter as I was editing it for clarity

[image]

The advantage of this approach is that the report can handle as few or as many values as you like.